# How do I treat phrasal verbs in X-bar theory?

Tags: syntax-trees, x-bar-theory, phrasal-verbs

I need to draw the tree of this sentence according to x-bar theory.

> She would **back me up** when it was needed

What do I do with the phrasal verb with the pronoun in the middle?

Thank you!

Comment: As a note for anyone else seeing this—we have a rule against syntax tree questions, but personally I think this one is fine. It's asking about how to deal with a certain grammatical structure in a certain syntactic theory (which others might also have questions about in the future), rather than asking us to draw a tree for a specific sentence (which will probably not be helpful to anyone except the asker).

Comment: Well, I wouldn't venture to say what an X-bar grammarian might do, but I'd just consider the two as one unit that has a detachable part, and rules about how to detach it. Much the same can be said for a prepositional phrase that gets stranded or extraposition from NP. Oh, and if you're not a linguist, you have no reason to treat anything in X-bar theory, because only (some) linguists have any use for it.

Comment: Well, "me" is object of "back" and "up" is a stranded preposition functioning as complement of "back". But that's a _normal_ analysis, not an x-bar one.

Comment: The question is hinting at a weakness of phrase structure syntax in general, not just of X-bar theoretical accounts. The verb and the particle are non-adjacent, which is definitely problematic insofar as they clearly form a semantic unit. Thus, there is a clear semantic unit that does not correspond directly to a syntactic constituent. In a dependency grammar, however, the two are linked by a dependency, which means they form an identifiable unit of dependency syntax.

Comment: @TimOsborne I wouldn't call "up" a particle since it is unable to occur between the verb and its direct object. I'd simply label "me" and "up" as complements of "back", the former being object.

Comment: @BillJ. The use of terminology varies. Some call those words _intransitive prepositions_. I (and others) call them _particles_. The term _complement_ is also appropriate, although that term is much broader in what it can denote.

Comment: @TimOsborne  Yes, intransitive prepositions since they are one-word phrases. Yes, the term 'complement' is appropriate, but that's a function term. The word class (POS) is preposition, though there are one or two particles that consist of an adjective.